# Pass Leaflet Draw Marker to Turf.js point

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, leaflet-draw, turf

I am trying to dynamically supply `turf.point([coordinate array])` with values from leaflet.draw markers.

I can only find hard coded examples for all turf examples.

I will demonstrate:

```
// Draw controls
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polygon:false,
        polyline: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: {
            icon: cssIcon
        },
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

     map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
            //Grab Coordinates As Array
        }

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });

////////////////////////////////
// Pass marker to turf.point
var point = turf.point([*Pass Array Here*], {
    "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
    "title": "Start Point"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the marker's coordinates from the `draw:created` event like this: `e.layer._latlng`

You can then pass these coordinates to your Turf.js function like this:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
      layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'marker') {
      //Grab Coordinates As Array
      var lnglat = [e.layer._latlng.lng, e.layer._latlng.lat];
      passToTurf(lnglat)
  }

  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

////////////////////////////////
// Pass marker to turf.point
function passToTurf(lnglat){
  var point = turf.point(lnglat, {
    "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
    "title": "Start Point"
  });
}
```

Please note that Leaflet 0.7 stores coordinates in [latitude, longitude] pairs while Turf.js uses [longitude, latitude].

Answer (score -1):

this is may be not an answer for your question, but I think it will be valuable for a beginner (like me), playing with leaflet and turf, using toGeoJSON() function directly, without storing points as array first.

This is my code snippet, based on Leaflet.draw provided [full.html](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/examples/full.html) example (with additional [turf.min.js](https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js))

```
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});
        map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.04), zoom: 13}),
        drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
        edit: { featureGroup: drawnItems }
    }));

    map.on('draw:created', function(event) {
        var layer = event.layer;

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });


    //turf control panel on bottom right of map
    var turfControlPanel = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
    turfControlPanel.onAdd = function(map){
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'myclass');
        div.innerHTML= "<input id='tin' type='button' value='do tin'/>"
            +"<input id='convex' type='button' value='do convex'/>";
        return div;
    }
    turfControlPanel.addTo(map);

    //store turf results to ease debugging
    var currentConvex;
    var currentTin; 

    //handle clicking on our control panel
    L.DomUtil.get('tin').onclick = function () {
        currentTin = turf.tin(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
        L.geoJson(currentTin).addTo(map);
    }
    L.DomUtil.get('convex').onclick = function () {
        currentConvex = turf.convex(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
        L.geoJson(currentConvex).addTo(map);
    }
```